# Cannot rebuild CMake after I have moved folders down one directory

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I have moved my entire CMake projects down one directory to be inside a new directory called `resources/...`.

Doing so, I now received this error.

```
CMake Error: The source "C:/.../CMake_tutorial/resources/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "C:/.../CMake_tutorial/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
```

I can only get this to work with a command line execution using `cmake --fresh -S . -B build`, but I would like to use the GUI. I have deleted all the previous builds and caches but it keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

On the GUI in the upper left corner their is a "Delete Cache" option. This is how it was resolved, not deleting a file.